# ReactJS How do I use state hooks for a list of text changing buttons with a timeout?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

This may be confusing but I appreciate the help. I essentially have a list of data with a "Copy" button next to each one. On click I want it to change to "Copied!" for 500 milliseconds and then go back to "Copy".

My setup is as follows: I have an array with the list of data that I've passed as a prop into a component (lets say array x).

Using this array I create a useEffect hook (that updates when the data array x is updated). This hook updates a new state with the new array (lets say array y) of the length of the original array with the text "Copy".

Seems to work great as far as I can tell, now heres where my problem is:
I then create a handler for the button where I create a new array, using the dot notation spread and update the index of the button from "Copy" to "Copied!". Then a time out puts it back to "Copy" (code below).

Works great, but as you suspect I have a bug. If I hit copy on another button too quickly, I end up with the original "copied" button stuck there. As I'm guessing I'm updating the state faster then the other state drops back.

```
function copyButtonClipBrd(index) {
  console.log("Test Copy Button");
  console.log(cpyBTN);
  let newArr = [...cpyBTN];
  newArr[index] = "Copied!";
  setCpyBTN(newArr);
  
  setTimeout(function () {
    let newArr = [...cpyBTN];
    newArr[index] = "Copy";
    setCpyBTN(newArr);
  }, 600);
}
```

Would love any advice, or even better ways to do this as I'm largely doing this for learning. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to update the state, when any button is clicked, just to show a different text on the button.

Add a click event listener on the parent element of the list that contains all the data and check if the element that triggered the `click` event is a copy button or not. If it is, change its text and also set a timer that will revert the text back to "Copy"

#### Demo:

```js
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos';

function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState([]);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(todos => setTodos(todos))
      .catch(err => console.log(err.message));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TodoList todos={todos}/>
    </div>
  );
}

function TodoList(props) {

  function changeBtnText(event) {
    const target = event.target;

    if (target.matches("button")) {
      target.textContent = "Copied";
      setTimeout(() => (target.textContent = "Copy"), 1000);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="todoList" onClick={changeBtnText}>
      {props.todos.map(t => (
        <Todo key={t.id} {...t} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

function Todo({ title, completed }) {
  return (
    <div className="todo">
      <span>TItle: {title}</span>
      <button>Copy</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.todo {
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.todo button {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

You can also view this demo on Codesandbox

[image: Edit hardcore-leaf-oxpf6]

Comment: Hi thank you for this, it works great, and so simple to do. I think its because I learned about state that I'm trying to use it everywhere, but is there a good reason or idea when its okay not to use it (such as for this).

Comment: in this case, it was unnecessary and inefficient to update the state when any button was clicked because whole data list was being re-rendered when you update the state on a button click.

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue with using the state directly for manipulations for it, instead ReactJS provides a callback version of `setState` which allows you to access the `currentState` at the time of execution as a parameter. You can use this as:

```
setCpyBtn((currentState) => {
  return currentState.map((item, i) => {
    if (i === index) {
      return 'Copy';
    }
    return 'Copied';
  });
})
```

and of course vice versa.

[Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

Comment: Thanks friend, I'm used to using prevState in classes but wasn't sure there was similar with hooks. Cheers. I've tried the above, but I seem to get "'setCpyBtn' is not defined". I do have this inside the function copyButtonClipBrd(index) handler.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback, useRef } from 'react'
import { range } from 'lodash-es'

const App = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(
    range(100).map((val) => ({ id: val, val, text: 'Copy' })),
  )

  const [copiedItem, setCopiedItem] = useState<number | undefined>(undefined)

  const timeout = useRef<number | undefined>(undefined)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (copiedItem) {
      setItems((itemsState) =>
        itemsState.map((item) =>
          item.id === copiedItem
            ? { ...item, text: 'Copied' }
            : { ...item, text: 'Copy' },
        ),
      )
    } else {
      setItems((itemsState) =>
        itemsState.map((item) => ({ ...item, text: 'Copy' })),
      )
    }
  }, [copiedItem])

  const handleClick = useCallback(
    (itemId) => () => {
      if (timeout.current) {
        window.clearTimeout(timeout.current)
      }
      setCopiedItem(itemId)
      timeout.current = window.setTimeout(() => {
        setCopiedItem(undefined)
      }, 1000)
    },
    [],
  )

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.id} className="mb-4">
          <span className="mr-2">{item.val}</span>
          <button className="p-2 bg-gray-100" onClick={handleClick(item.id)}>
            {item.text}
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

- You can use another state `copiedItem` which either stores the id or the index of the item which is set to be copied. In the `useEffect` we can look for the change in `copiedItem` to set the text to be *Copied*.
- In addition to that we also need a reference to the previous timeout, so that we could clear it before triggering the next items timeout.

Answer (score 1):

So I tried this using @Agney suggestion to use callback in setState. here is codesanbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-dubinsky-lm03x?file=/src/App.js

so basically we are checking index in setstate callback to initially set it to copied and in timeout callback we are again checking same index to set back to copy.